# How to null check and index check these JAXB types of classes

Tags: java, coding-style, jaxb

I have been provided an XSD file to unmarshall the XML returned from an external web service.

I'm able to unmarshall the XML I receive into the JAXB classes. But due to the depth of the structure of the JAXB classes generated I'm not sure on how to **null** check the code while retrieving values.

Example to retrieve a students name, the code is as follows -

```
jaxbResponse.getStudentDetails().get(0).getStudent().get(0).getName().get(0).getGivenName();
```

It gets really messy if I have to **null** check and **index** check the lists this code returns.

This is just an example, I need to get around 50 parameters with code similar to the above code. I have no idea when I'm going to get a **NullPointerException** or an **IndexOutofBoundsException**.

I'm new to working with JaxB classes, I need some help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good question. I am facing the same problem. I have lots of elements that are defined `minOccurs="0"` I need to `null` check them all. It would be cool if there was a more generic solution.

Comment: I tried hard to find a generic solution but I did not find anything simple. Please let me know if you find something interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern of your example looks like a List generated from a simple `<xs:element minOccurs="{something}" maxOccurs="unbounded">` in which case you should never get a `null` List (though you may get an empty list if `minOccurs` is 0), and you won't get `null` values out of the list either. You'll only have to worry about nulls if you have an `@XmlElementWrapper` or your schema declares elements as nillable.

I can't be more specific without seeing (at least an extract from) your schema and/or generated classes.

Comment: Yes I agree with your reply, I'm never going to get a null value but I get an indexOutofBoundsException everytime the list is empty. Do I have any option other then checking if the list is empty or not all the time.

Comment: Not really, apart from maybe nested foreach loops. Much of my day to day programming these days is in Groovy, and going back to Java I really miss the `?.` safe navigation operator...

Comment: There are many attributes in the XSD which are optional so I guess will have to null check only some of the values. Thanks for your explanation, it made me understand XSD's better.